# How can I gracefully handle a failed tcpSocket.connect attempt?

Tags: node.js

The following code causes an error when there is no existing TCP server to communicate with on the specified host:

```
const net = require('net');
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

try {
    var tcpSocket = new net.Socket();
    tcpSocket.connect(argv.tcpport, argv.tcphost, function onConnected() {
        console.log('connected');
        tcpSocket.on('data', function onIncoming(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

        tcpSocket.on('close', function onClose(data) {
            tcpSocketConnected = false;
        });

        tcpSocketConnected = true;
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log("PRINT ME: ", err);
}
```

Error:

> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1906
>       at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
>       at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)

I am unable to catch the error even though I wrap the code in a `try...catch`.

- Why does my catch block not catch the error?
- How can I gracefully handle the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to explicitly handle the [`error`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_error) event using event emitter api (same way as you handled `close` and `data`):

`tcpSocket.on('error', handleError)`

From Docs:

```
Event: 'error'#
Added in: v0.1.90
<Error>
Emitted when an error occurs. Unlike net.Socket, the 'close' event 
will not be emitted directly following this event unless server.close() 
is manually called. See the example in discussion of server.listen().
```